# Adjust quotas in a microstack deployment

Tags: openstack

Is there a way to adjust quotas in a microstack/openstack workstation test deployment? In particular, limiting security groups doesn't allow for a test run of even two web applications?

Comment: 18.04.3 LTS Bionic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had this issue today, and changed the quota from 10 to 20 as below

```
sudo snap install openstackclients --classic
openstack quota show
```

Get your project id and check the quota for secgroups:

```
openstack quota set --secgroups 20 <project id>
```

This worked using 18.04 LTS.